# Is requesting removal of a single incorrect tag big enough to make an edit?

Tags: discussion, tags

A question has a tag that is completely unrelated to the question (in fact the tag wasn't added by OP, but by another user who did nothing, but add tags, one of them is ok, the other is not). Is requesting removal of the incorrect tag a superfluous edit?

Comment: For a more accurate answer, provide a link to the question.

Comment: @James The question in question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410227/test-if-object-implements-interface/26780025. It's tagged with [tag:testing] with likely was an ambiguous tag in the past, but now relates to software testing, however the question has nothing to do with software testing. I tried to edit it, but first time around I was denied because I also tried to add [tag:oop] at the same time. I tried again without adding anything and got http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7374353. So I figured I must be doing something wrong and asked here to correct my ways.

Comment: @jahu I agreed that `testing` should go away.  So I did it.  Apologize for those who want to see the problem.

Comment: That question is a **duplicate** it should be marked as such and deleted!

Comment: Given the 4 downvotes and 0 upvotes on my answer, I would suggest the tag excerpt and description are edited to be a little more clear. It may be clear to those who *know* and *already understand it*, but there are obviously people not sure and using it incorrectly. Given 18K questions with that tag, and the desc/excerpt being a *little* open to interpretation, I would imagine there to be a fair few incorrectly tagged questions.

Comment: @James Actually renaming the tag to [tag:software-testing] might make it less prone to misuse.

Comment: But my confusion was with *both* of those words. So it's just confirming what the desc and excerpt already explains (Just saying, as someone new to the tag and possibly a representative of similar noobs)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The question might be or have duplicates, but it's not flagged as duplicate nor there are other questions flagged as duplicate of that one. Assuming it's actually a duplicate of another, with this many views and quite a few up votes the question is valuable (in many ways) and by no means should be deleted. Flagging as duplicate != flagging for deletion.

Answer (score 11):

It's value is dependent on context.  One couldn't say in the general case.

Is having incorrect tag going to end up exposing the question to a lot of people that shouldn't see it?  (For example, tagging a C++ question as C# is showing it to tons of people who have no interest in seeing it.)

Does it give a false impression about what the question is about, making it appear that the question is asking something that it's not?  (For example, having a question tagged with a version of a tool/language that is different from what is actually being used.)

If there is a tag that doesn't have a lot of followers, is just superfluous (in that it doesn't add additional useful information/visibility to the question) and that doesn't confuse readers as to what the question is actually asking about, then it's something that's worth removing *as a part of a more comprehensive edit*, but not in and of itself.

Answer (score 11):

I would say it's a perfectly valid edit suggestion to just remove an incorrect tag. After all, one of the privileges is the ability to quick-edit the tags (and only the tags) of a question. From this, I conclude that tag-only edits are considered valid, so suggesting them must be such as well.

Answer (score 7):

It depends.

In general, correcting tagging is both one of the fastest and highest ROI edits.
Still, try to make your edit count by at least correcting (most) other glaringly obvious deficiencies.

Tags are used for categorizing questions, which means any question wrongly tagged diminishes the tags usefulness, both locally and globally.

Locally, it distorts the question, making it unclear.
Globally, it makes finding relevant questions harder.

Unless a tag is pretty-much a null-value, in which case it should simply be destroyed as useless by moderator fiat, the question will be deleted by the roomba shortly anyway, or the post is SPAM / OFFENSIVE and thus editing is contra-productive for any reason, correcting categorization is always worthwhile.

---

Regarding your suggestions:

- [The first was actually not good](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7370629). The question is not about [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop), thus the rejection was proper. (As an aside, the only reviewer above 3000 voted to reject (45K).)
- [The second was simply unfortunate](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7374353). This time around, you are restricting yourself to the correct part of your edit-suggestion, only removing [testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing). (As an aside, this time the only reviewer with more than 3000 voted to reject too (6k). Not that he has that much more than the others...)